# @Mock annotation not working on an Object Mapper

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write JUnit test cases for one of my projects where I am trying to mock an object mapper and use it in the test case. But when I try to debug the junit test case, it fails immediately with the below error.

I have gone through some blogs and started using @MockBean annotation on the objectMapper. In this case, the mapper value is being null and the test case is failing. Could someone help me here.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability;
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:240)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:228)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1908)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:44)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:19)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:49)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:80)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Here is the test class where I mocked the ObjectMapper and the method I am testing

```
@Mock
ObjectMapper mapper;

final String messageType = "TEST";
final String env = "TEST";

@Test
public void myMethodTest() throws Exception
{
  Mockito.when(mapper.readValue(Mockito.anyString(), eq(someClass.class))).thenReturn(obj);


public void myMethod(Order order)
{

    try {
        Order someClassObj = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonObj), Order.class);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to declare the whole class in the example.

When you use `@Mock`, `@InjectMocks`, `@Captor` and other Mockito annotations your test class must have `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

Example:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private MyService service;

   @Mock
   private ObjectMapper mapper;

   @Test
   public void myTest(){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: The issue was with the version of Maven I have been using. I have downgraded the version of Maven and things started working as you stated in your example.